# Page not found(404) error in django

Tags: python, django

I am getting a 404 error if the activation url is wrong or invalid.

accounts/urls.py --

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r"^signup/$", views.signup, name="account_signup"),
    url(r'^login/$', views.login_view, name='account_login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', auth_views.logout, {'next_page': '/account/login'}, name='logout'),
    url(r'^confirmemail/$', views.confirmemail, name='account_confirmemail'),
    url(r'^activate/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$',views.activate, name='activate'),
]
```

accounts/views.py

```
def activate(request, uidb64, token):
    try:
        uid = force_text(urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64))
        user = User.objects.get(pk=uid)
    except (TypeError, ValueError, OverflowError, User.DoesNotExist):
        user = None

    if user is not None and account_activation_token.check_token(user, token):
        user.is_active = True
        user.profile.email_confirmed = True
        user.save()
        user.profile.save()
        login(request, user)
        return redirect('home')
    else:
        return render(request, 'accounts/account_activation_invalid.html')
        #return HttpResponseRedirect("account_activation_invalid.html")
```

It should redirect to `account_activation_invalid.html` if the account activation url is wrong.

Any help/links is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Django uses regular expressions for URL matching, if activation url is not proper (i.e. one of the nested argument might be missing) then this is no match. Which means your view code is not executed and 404 is thrown by Django.

Comment: Thanks @anuragal for the explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understand correctly, you can try:

in urls.py add:

```
url(r'^activate/',views.activate, name='empty_activate')
```

in views change definitio to:

```
def activate(request, uidb64=None, token=None):
```

Comment: Brilliant. It worked. Sorry I couldn't understand why it is necessary to set `uidb64=None, token=None`.